# Bill of materials and versioning

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

For our custom stock management system, we define our machine parts and assembled products in a `tpart` table. To define the bill of materials we have a `tbom` table.

[image]

Every part has a revision (a change is made, and the part is still interchangeable with a previous revision; in other words: two parts - same id - with different revision are one-on-one replaceable).

What we need is a revision history. What is the best way to achieve this?

- Is the composite primary key in `tbom` the right way?
- Every time we create a new revision, will we need to copy all entries from the previous revision (in `tbom`) to entries for the new revision?
- When a child part is changed, do all parent parts have to update their BOM and/or revision?

Or is it better practice to have a separate `trevision` table?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a following design for your case.

[image: tbom table]

[image: revision_history table]

You can have following benefits by adding new revision history table.

- You do not have to store (or clone) parentpart_id and subpart_id for
  every revision. This will allow you to decrease the size of table by
  eliminating unnecessary information.
- You can store unlimited number revision records for each bom item.
- You can set up more efficient structure by joining foreign keys.
- You can add additional history detail fields to new table such as
  revision_purpose,recorded_issues etc. Alternatively you can create
  following new table to store details of revisions.

[image: revision_history_detail table]

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Two remarks: 1) 'subpart_id' is a foreign key as well (from tpart). 2) I don't see how 'revision_history' uses 'tbom_id'. Every id in 'tbom' identifies the quantity a part is needed in its parent-part. For every subpart belonging to a parentpart there is an entry in 'revision_history'? How are 'tbom.date' and 'revision_history.revision_date' related?

Comment: (X) It is necessary to save tbom_id to revision_history by reading it from tbom table.  (X) if date value in tbom is revision date, of course it is unnecessary. If so, it should be deleted from tbom.